# Return two lists to the view c# mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have two lists that i want to return to the view, 'added' and 'removed'. However currently i can only return either the 'added' or 'removed'. How can i return both in one object? I am very new to MVC so apologies if this code is messy!

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // Excel upload history

        var fptexcel = db.FPTStaticDataRatedFinancialAssetBase
                       .OrderBy(e => e.FORATExcelId)
                       .Select(e => e.FORATExcelId).Max();

        var fptexcelprevious = fptexcel - 1;

        var newassets = db.FPTStaticDataRatedFinancialAssetBase.OfType<FPTStaticDataRatedFinancialAssetBase>()
                        .Where(c => c.FORATExcelId == fptexcel || c.FORATExcelId == fptexcelprevious)
                        .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
                        .Where(c => c.Count() == 1)
                        .Select(y => y.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();

        var added = db.FPTStaticDataRatedFinancialAssetBase.OfType<FPTStaticDataRatedFinancialAssetBase>()
                         .Where(x => x.FORATExcelId == fptexcelprevious)
                         .Select(x => x).ToList();

        var removed = db.FPTStaticDataRatedFinancialAssetBase.OfType<FPTStaticDataRatedFinancialAssetBase>()
                         .Where(x => x.FORATExcelId == fptexcel)
                         .Select(x => x).ToList();

        return View(newassets.Except(added).ToList());

    }
```

Comment: Do you want them to be in the same list or two seperate lists?

Comment: Well I have two html grid's in the view, one for assets added and one for assets removed, so i guess they need to remain split?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Strongly type your view so it as an associated model that is a custom object that contains both lists. Note such an object is often referred as a "viewModel".

Example:

Your viewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public List<X> Added { get; set; }
    public List<X> Removed { get; set; }
}
```

Your controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var viewModel = new MyViewModel
    {
        Added = ...,
        Removed = ...
    };
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Your view:

```
@model XXXXX.MyViewModel
...
```

Comment: And as an addendum, in order to access the list in the view, you would use syntax such as '@Model.Added' and '@Model.Removed'

Answer (score 7):

Why not having a ViewModel containing these 2 lists

```
return View(new MyModel{List1 = list1,List2 = list2});
```

or

```
ViewData["List1"] = list1;
ViewData["List2"] = list2;
return View();
```

have a look here: http://www.howmvcworks.net/OnViews/BuildingAStronglyTypedView

I think you want the first one.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest ViewData, the first way, is the best way.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the dynamic type like ViewBag

You can access @viewbag in Razor View